# Do condition formats in if/else if statements have to match in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have an if statement in C that is a string comparison and an else if statement that is a character comparison. For some reason, it skips the else if statement completely. I am wondering if the condition formats have to match.

```
if(!strcmp(pitchtomidi[j][0], "C4")) 
     {
         printf("This is the midi number of the string in question: %s\n", pitchtomidi[j][0]);
     }

else if(pitchtomidi[j][0][0] == '/')
     {
           printf("This is the character in question: %c\n", pitchtomidi[j][0][0]);
     }
```

**Example Input 1:** "/"

Output: This is the character in question: /

**Example Input 2:** "/3"

No output ever occurs for this, despite the slash still being the first character.

Comment: *for some reason, it is not working correctly* -- can you elaborate? Do you see any errors? Do you see wrong behavior? Can you provide a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just modified it to mention that it skipped the else if part completely and I added the example output.

Comment: Can you also tell us what the input was (what was in `pitchtomidi[j][0]` ?)

Comment: Just added the inputs/outputs.

Comment: No, there is no [MCVE] yet. If the string pointed to by `pitchtomidi[j][0]` is `"/3"`, then the `if` in `else` would match.

Comment: I modified the inputs/outputs in my question. I get an output for / but not for /3. I wonder why it's not matching on my end?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what output do you get for an input of `"C4"`?

Comment: My program converts alphabetic/solfege input into midi equivalents based on a lookup table, so I currently get "60" for the input C4, corresponding to midi note 60.

Comment: Your revised code works perfectly for me, when I add some "reasonable" surrounding code -- "reasonable" to me, that is.  So I'm guessing that your problem has to do with your own surrounding code, which we obviously can't see or debug.  In particular, what is the declaration of `pitchtomidi`?

Comment: const char *pitchtomidi[121][7] = {
     {"31", "Fx1", "fy1", "G1", "so1", "Abb1", "lu1"},
     {"32", "G#1", "si1", "0", "0", "Ab1", "le1"},
     {"33", "Gx1", "sy1", "A1", "la1", "Bbb1", "tu1"},
     {"34", "A#1", "li1", "0", "0", "Bb1", "te1"}, etc.

Comment: What I meant was, if you enter `"C4"`, does it print `"This is the string in question: C4"`?

Comment: No, it prints "This is the string in question: 60". I just revised my question to make the printf statement more sensible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195832/discussion-between-nakul-tiruviluamala-and-steve-summit).

Answer (score 3):

`else` *does not have a condition*, so no, nothing has to match.

In your example, after the else you have an additional `if`, with a new condition. If this condition is not true, the respective `else` for that `if` would be executed (which doesn't exist).

Here is what you wrote, extended to make it clearer:

```
if(!strcmp(pitchtomidi[j][0], "C4")) 
     {
         printf("This is the string in question %s\n", pitchtomidi[j][0]);
     }

else
     if(pitchtomidi[j][0][0] == '/')
         {
               printf("This is the character in question %c\n", pitchtomidi[j][0][0]);
         }
     else
         {
               /* do nothing */
         }
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I modified my question so that it is asking if "if" and "else if" conditions need to match.